# A word for a fallen tree with roots exposed

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

I'm looking for a single word or an idiom for a fallen tree with roots exposed, or a cavity formed between the roots of a fallen tree and the soil. Preferably an uncommon poetic/dialect word

Comment: From the SWR tag comments: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word.  INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. "

Comment: The tree is 'uprooted', trivially. A quick search for synonyms is unhelpful, answers addressing only the metaphorical sense (eg 'extirpated').

Comment: "Downed" would fit the tree being knocked over.